# Illegal start of expression and expected ';' errors in Android code

Tags: android

I just wanted to create an application that works like an HTML page or something. Just after clicked button, new site is opening.

I don't know why there are 5 errors: 2 Errors:(15, 11 and 15,18) error: illegal start of expression, and 2 Errors:(15, 31  and 15,41) error: ';' expected.

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    {
    public void nextStep(View view) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondaryActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
     }
 }
 }
```

Coud you help me? :/

Comment: can you please format the question ? @ Paulsen11

Comment: Right after `setContentView()`, the closing bracket is reversed. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); {` should be `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); }`. Notice closing bracket instead of opening one.

Answer (score 0):

your message is not formated 
It shows like if

`{ public void nextStep(View view) {Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondaryActivity.class);startActivity(i); }`

is inside you onCreate function,

if true, you can't write a function inside another function

Answer (score 0):

There was problem with bracket.Try this

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void nextStep(View view) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondaryActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
}
```